# Problema con llave foránea oracle sql server

Tags: oracle

El problema es que cuando intento agregar un registro, una llave foránea que une las 2 tablas, me da el siguiente error "restricción de integridad (PLANILLA.PLA_AFP_FK1) violada - clave principal no encontrada"

esto ocurre solo si el ID es diferente a 9, ya que el Id que tengo en la otra tabla es 9
Integro imagenes que describan mejor el problema.

estoy usando Angular y nodejs para realizar este programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
router.post('/empleado', async(req, res) => {



const values = [
    req.body.COD_CIA,
    req.body.COD_NEGOCIO,
    req.body.COD_EMPLEADO,
    req.body.PRIMER_NOMBRE,
    req.body.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
    req.body.PRIMER_APELLIDO,
    req.body.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
    req.body.COD_AFP,
    req.body.FECHA_NACIMIENTO
]

let condicional = await DB.query("SELECT * FROM PLA_EMPLEADOS WHERE COD_CIA= :v1", [req.body.COD_CIA], false);

console.log(condicional);

if (condicional.rows.length == 0) {
    let ing = await DB.query("INSERT INTO PLA_EMPLEADOS (COD_CIA, COD_NEGOCIO, COD_EMPLEADO, PRIMER_NOMBRE, SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, PRIMER_APELLIDO, SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, COD_AFP, FECHA_NACIMIENTO) VALUES (:COD_CIA, :COD_NEGOCIO, :COD_EMPLEADO, :PRIMER_NOMBRE, :SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, :PRIMER_APELLIDO, :SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, :COD_AFP, :FECHA_NACIMIENTO)", values, true)



    res.json({ data: ing, error: null })
} else {
    res.json({ data: null, error: "YA HAY UN USUARIO CON ESTE CODIGO" })


}
```

})

Comment: Podrias mostrar los querys con los datos que queres ingresar? no entiendo si tu problema no es que simplemente te faltan datos...

Comment: ya lo agrego...

Comment: ingresé los que son mas importantes, ya que los otros segun entiendo, no generarían ningun problema, ya que son null

Comment: Porque agregas imagenes? es mucho mas facil para mi copiar tu codigo, si lo pones como codigo y no como imagen, incluso verlo...  No uses imagenes salvo que sea totalmente necesario...

Comment: ok, pasaré el código.

Comment: Te esta dando un error de integridad referencial.. eso quiere decir que tratas de meter datos que no estan en la otra tabla referenciada... ahora, no nos estas mostrando nada de eso.. seguro que una de las dos claves, no esta en la otra tabla.. que clave estas tratando de meter?? existe en la otra tabla?

Comment: estoy tratando de meter el "cod_afp", que es la unica que está en la otra tabla, pero tambien está "Cod_cia", que es como el Id, pero al parecer da problemas si el cod_cia de de la tabla afp no coincide con la tabla de empleados, y no puedo cambiarle el nombre a ese campo de la tabla afp porque la base no es mía

Comment: No tnes que cambiar nada, tenes que meter los registros respetando las claves que tenes...

Answer (score 0):

El problema que yo veo, es que en tu tabla PLA_EMPLEADOS tienes una llave apuntando a otra tabla y ella llave no existe en con el ID 1.

La llave foranea te sirve para declarar un tipo de relacion mastro-detalle y si no existe el dato en la tabla maestro, no puedes ingresar datos en la tabla detalle.

Es por eso que solo puedes ingresar registros con el ID 9, que es el que tienes registrado en tu tabla maestro.

Saludos
Israel Ramos